# HTTP POST to CouchDB via Javascript/JQuery errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, couchdb

Im trying to send a uttermost simple POST request to CouchDB in every possible way, but it wont work.. The database consists of documents with ID names of colors and a atribute with also the colorname (first in Dutch, the in English) and im trying to add a document.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/colors',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {"Kleur": "PURPLE"},
        crossDomain: true,
        success:function(response, status){
                 alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                 console.log("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);
        }
    });
```

The code above gives me a 400 Bad Request error. Why i dont know.. 
When i did the POST request to posttestserver.com it says that there were no POST variables but the POST body was 12 chars long.

This is the other code i tried:

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:5984/colors", //Required URL of the page on server
    { // Data Sending With Request To Server
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {"Kleur": "PURPLE"},
        crossDomain: true,
    },
    function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
        alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
        console.log("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);
    });
```

This time i get a 415 Unsupported Mediatype error and when i POST to posttestserver.com it says it has 3 POST variables but no POST body anymore..

I also tried stuff with jsonp and added orgins = * to the local.ini

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you might be using the wrong syntax. Instead of

"contentType: 'application/json',"

try

"dataType: "json","

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: When i add and/or replace dataType: "json" the AJAX call just doenst do anything and the .post doenst show any difference : /